# application force closing

Tags: android, forceclose

This is my logcat and the problem is that the application is force closing and i want to knw the line or method which is causing this. I m new to android so cant understand a word of logcat. Thanks in advance

```
01-16 17:32:56.584: D/dalvikvm(276): GC freed 596 objects / 49984 bytes in 101ms
01-16 17:33:09.233: D/AndroidRuntime(276): Shutting down VM
01-16 17:33:09.233: W/dalvikvm(276): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-16 17:33:09.233: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ymappuser/com.ymappuser.Manualloc}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.ymappuser.Manualloc.getCountries(Manualloc.java:270)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.ymappuser.Manualloc.fillcountry(Manualloc.java:83)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.ymappuser.Manualloc.onCreate(Manualloc.java:75)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 11 more
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  at com.ymappuser.Manualloc.getCountries(Manualloc.java:243)
01-16 17:33:09.273: E/AndroidRuntime(276):  ... 15 more
01-16 17:33:09.384: I/dalvikvm(276): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-16 17:33:09.404: I/dalvikvm(276): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
01-16 17:33:11.353: I/Process(276): Sending signal. PID: 276 SIG: 9
01-16 17:33:13.004: D/dalvikvm(284): GC freed 623 objects / 51024 bytes in 125ms
01-16 17:34:21.646: D/dalvikvm(284): GC freed 288 objects / 14672 bytes in 987ms
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation wouldn't hurt (what's your app, when does it happen, etc.) There is a NullPointerException being thrown when executing Manualloc.getCountries (line 243), probably in your onCreate. Please post the code of method getCountries

Comment: Take a look at line 243 in your Manualloc class. Before anyone will answer this properly, you'll need to clearly state your question with additional info like the concerning code.

Comment: Thanks buddy, Really was in hurry so couldnt post the full question. But i sorted it out. The method was getting data from a webservice and the xml i was reading was carrying an element with null its value. Got it sorted. But really sorry if i troubled u. never again ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting null pointer exception in method getCountries, in class Manualloc at line 270, you can check there by debugging what object on the line is null, and work accordingly.

Comment: Got it jitendra. I was trying to access an null object that was coming from the webservice in xml format. It was carrying null. and i was assigning it to textview.